# How do I return GPS Coordinates for specific street signs in Toronto?

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, mapillary

I need help returning all GPS Coordinates for street signs in Canada. I used Mapillary to find the locations of these signs but the zoom is too small and it doesn't return any GPS Coordinates. It just shows you the location of them on a map. I tried using https://overpass-turbo.eu/ but I have no coding experience and have no idea how to filter for specific street signs.

I posted a picture of some of the signs I need across the country.
How do I get this data?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Toronto, Ontario** has poles as open data.

This will give you the precise location and elevation of your signs.
(data has a ground accuracy of +- 30cm.)
[image]

How you cross reference that with your requirements is going to be a challenge, but this will give you a good start.

Data was downloaded from
https://open.toronto.ca/dataset/topographic-mapping-poles/